# The IP address returned by whatismyipaddress.com belongs to whom?

Tags: networking, internet-connection, ip-address

I am using Wi-Fi on a home network and I just checked the public IP address through [whatismyipaddress.com](https://whatismyipaddress.com/).

Is it the IP address of my router? If not, to whom does it belong? Could somebody explain the topology of a home Wi-Fi internet network, with regards to IP address?

Comment: it could be your home router, but ISPs have many different architectures internally. we cannot categorically say anything for sure. Many ISPs allocate a user a specific public IP, and while that may or may not be your routers WAN IP, it will allow solicited and unsolicited traffic to come to your device. other ISPs will use technologies like CGNAT, where each user does not have a unique public IP, which will enable you to connect outbound to services, but will not allow you to run services of your own (without more complex measures). so short answer, it depends...

Answer (score 3):

Oversimplifying  (ie for the 2 most common cases for IPv4) - The IP address likely belongs to your ISP, and is typically either

- The IP address associated with the WAN interface of your router or
- If you are behind Carrier Grade NAT, an IP address of the router at your ISP which is making the request to whatismyipaddress.com on your behalf.

**To explain the topology of the common home WIFI network network case: (again, simplifying a lot)**

Your router typically has 2 interfaces - the WAN interface which goes to your ISP and LAN Interface where your home devices connect to.

The LAN Interface often includes 4 ports - ie a switch where you can plug devices on your LAN into it on the Ethernet cable.  It also includes the WIFI network.    The relevant part here, is that other then that it's happening over WIFI and there is a passphrase and SSID associated with it, Ethernet and WIFI have the same format and are treated identically.

Historically, it was common for a single real-world routable IP address to be assigned to your router, and for the router to perform NAT (network address translation) between it and all the devices on the LAN - in this use case, the IP address returned by whatismyipaddress.com will be the IP address assigned by your ISP to the WAN interface of your router.

As IP (ie IP version 4) space has become scarce, ISPs don't always provide a real world routable IP address to your router. Rather, they provide it a special address which is used for CGN (Carrier Grade NAT).  Your ISP then has a router - or series of routers - which share your WAN IP address with a whole lot of others and make requests.

Answer (score 1):

Are you are talking about IP4 or IP6?

Yes, it **can** be the **public IP address** of your router.

Another likely scenario, especially with IP4, is that it could be a "shared" IP address for more than one router if your ISP uses [carrier grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). In this scenario, your router will get a private IP from your ISP which is different from the IP `whatismyipaddress.com` shows you.